# Looping OpenSSL SHA512 in C yields different results from PHP

Tags: php, c, openssl, cryptography, sha512

**UPDATE: PROBLEM SOLVED**

As commented below by several generous people, the problem was related to string functions used when dealing with raw bytes. Main issue was the use of **sprintf** inside the loop, which now I changed to **memmove**. Updated code follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <openssl/evp.h>
#include <openssl/bio.h>

/*
    Don't forget the compile switches:
    gcc sha.c -lssl -lcrypto -lm -o sha
 */
typedef struct {
    unsigned char raw_hash[EVP_MAX_MD_SIZE];
    size_t hash_len;
} HashResult;


/*
    adapted from https://gist.github.com/barrysteyn/4409525
 */
int Base64Encode(const char* message, unsigned int message_size, char** buffer) { //Encodes a string to base64
  BIO *bio, *b64;
  FILE* stream;
  int encodedSize = 4*ceil((double)message_size/3);
  *buffer = (char *)malloc(encodedSize+1);

  stream = fmemopen(*buffer, encodedSize+1, "w");
  b64 = BIO_new(BIO_f_base64());
  bio = BIO_new_fp(stream, BIO_NOCLOSE);
  bio = BIO_push(b64, bio);
  BIO_set_flags(bio, BIO_FLAGS_BASE64_NO_NL); //Ignore newlines - write everything in one line
  BIO_write(bio, message, message_size);
  BIO_flush(bio);
  BIO_free_all(bio);
  fclose(stream);

  return (0); //success
}


HashResult HashThis(char message[], int m_len, EVP_MD_CTX mdctx) {
    unsigned char md_value[EVP_MAX_MD_SIZE];
    int md_len;
    EVP_DigestInit_ex(&mdctx, EVP_sha512(), NULL);
    EVP_DigestUpdate(&mdctx, message, m_len);
    EVP_DigestFinal_ex(&mdctx, md_value, &md_len);

    HashResult hash;
    memcpy(hash.raw_hash, md_value, md_len);
    hash.hash_len = md_len;

    return hash;
}


main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i, l;
    char salt[256] = "SALT";
    char pass[256] = "PASSWORD";
    char salted[512];
    char digest[512];
    char* base64EncodeOutput;
    sprintf(salted, "%s{%s}", pass, salt);
    printf("C: Salted is: >>>>>>%s<<<<<<\n", salted);

    EVP_MD_CTX mdctx;
    OpenSSL_add_all_digests();
    EVP_MD_CTX_init(&mdctx);

    int s_len = strlen(salted);
    HashResult h_result = HashThis(salted, s_len, mdctx);
    memcpy(digest, h_result.raw_hash, h_result.hash_len);

    for(i = 1; i < 20; i++){
        memmove(digest+h_result.hash_len, salted, s_len);
        l = h_result.hash_len;
        h_result.hash_len = 0;
        memset(h_result.raw_hash, 0, l);
        h_result = HashThis(digest, (int)l+s_len, mdctx);
        memset(digest, 0, 512);
        memcpy(digest, h_result.raw_hash, h_result.hash_len);

        memset(base64EncodeOutput, 0, strlen(base64EncodeOutput));
        Base64Encode(digest, l, &base64EncodeOutput);
        printf("%d => %s\n", i, base64EncodeOutput);
    }

    EVP_MD_CTX_cleanup(&mdctx);
}
```

---

**ORIGINAL POST:**

I'm trying to implement in C the same key stretching as is done in PHP by Symfony's default password encoder:

```
<?php
$password = "PASSWORD";
$salt = "SALT";
$salted = $password."{".$salt."}";
$digest = hash("sha512", $salted, true);
echo "PHP: Salted is: >>>>>>$salted<<<<<<\n";

for ($i = 1; $i < 20; ++$i) {
    $digest = hash("sha512", $digest.$salted, true);
    $encoded_password = base64_encode($digest);
    echo "$i => $encoded_password\n";
}
?>
```

...trying this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <openssl/evp.h>
#include <openssl/bio.h>

/*
    Don't forget the compile switches:
    gcc sha.c -lssl -lcrypto -lm -o sha
 */
typedef struct {
    unsigned char raw_hash[EVP_MAX_MD_SIZE];
    size_t hash_len;
} HashResult;


/*
    adapted from https://gist.github.com/barrysteyn/4409525
 */
int Base64Encode(const char* message, unsigned int message_size, char** buffer) { //Encodes a string to base64
  BIO *bio, *b64;
  FILE* stream;
  int encodedSize = 4*ceil((double)message_size/3);
  *buffer = (char *)malloc(encodedSize+1);

  stream = fmemopen(*buffer, encodedSize+1, "w");
  b64 = BIO_new(BIO_f_base64());
  bio = BIO_new_fp(stream, BIO_NOCLOSE);
  bio = BIO_push(b64, bio);
  BIO_set_flags(bio, BIO_FLAGS_BASE64_NO_NL); //Ignore newlines - write everything in one line
  BIO_write(bio, message, message_size);
  BIO_flush(bio);
  BIO_free_all(bio);
  fclose(stream);

  return (0); //success
}


HashResult HashThis(char message[], EVP_MD_CTX mdctx) {
    unsigned char md_value[EVP_MAX_MD_SIZE];
    int md_len;
    EVP_DigestInit_ex(&mdctx, EVP_sha512(), NULL);
    EVP_DigestUpdate(&mdctx, message, strlen(message));
    EVP_DigestFinal_ex(&mdctx, md_value, &md_len);

    HashResult hash;
    memcpy(hash.raw_hash, md_value, md_len);
    hash.hash_len = md_len;

    return hash;
}


main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i, l;
    char salt[256] = "SALT";
    char pass[256] = "PASSWORD";
    char salted[512];
    char digest[512];
    char* base64EncodeOutput;
    sprintf(salted, "%s{%s}", pass, salt);
    printf("C: Salted is: >>>>>>%s<<<<<<\n", salted);

    EVP_MD_CTX mdctx;
    OpenSSL_add_all_digests();
    EVP_MD_CTX_init(&mdctx);

    HashResult h_result = HashThis(salted, mdctx);
    memcpy(digest, h_result.raw_hash, h_result.hash_len);

    for(i = 1; i < 20; i++){
        sprintf(digest, "%s%s", digest, salted);
        l = h_result.hash_len;
        h_result.hash_len = 0;
        memset(h_result.raw_hash, 0, l);
        h_result = HashThis(digest, mdctx);
        memset(digest, 0, 512);
        memcpy(digest, h_result.raw_hash, sizeof(h_result.raw_hash));

        memset(base64EncodeOutput, 0, strlen(base64EncodeOutput));
        Base64Encode(digest, l, &base64EncodeOutput);
        printf("%d => %s\n", i, base64EncodeOutput);
    }

    EVP_MD_CTX_cleanup(&mdctx);
}
```

...yields the following results:

```
C: Salted is: >>>>>>PASSWORD{SALT}<<<<<<
1 => 2yqDGoZ6NrdAKeS/yf7fCT/Zbv0/1Wa7cGwiy1pOvTpFE/I2Xfpajh8ukRhkM6j/8rv90C02ISeaz8K9awJLzw==
2 => QVn8YydCA/9J5j8YTnUlnDXtqq0yNRPVz2m1QFkZ7fwQBWY4rgjP/JUCIjQbL4JRyIZATf3Bsnh0OfhaT52f/A==
3 => ixpdJ4TaAY5POys95nhtU0Ghbu+yDgch3PL0UsPktxVUa5igEEdRmzMH5JZH7SrTkBaHUCa9ThKiSfA/TdbPog==
4 => Am1dkcqXZkXOfDuwsj/VaZy3j3CQnzDzbj1B4g4/dkCJ5g/0nXAti7PKdo5oxm8GIv3AoHHW6eldTbwGj3IgzA==
5 => mrfwPBiT3+TDl41xcf34p0A+eNHP18qWzm0uwOpzAarkfemzV5xsnz/x2QxuE4V7vNgYB8pVV6mYqRQkqitQRA==
6 => JIGX+XD6XVaPwP3LuJO/OToef2jBiCq70mKyg6PmvUARigS5VkZMrcbnI/PXdHXrZ081fVMYavJRsXJiXRhiaQ==
7 => oqU+PpM+HqJmUKcmOUMtIxvPgsCNyJ4zo+986ksr+Wvjp6ejDezFS49NuUXxi03GIj0ueLJxdPlIABvEBpd6RQ==
8 => lg8/4/xhjb0IIBndLnH00UM6Umyq5NrtwrwXcHCFgoRJK54m9sIUgtsPlJd7N3F1RDCoRhQBmXzrTz1vPXkQYQ==
9 => 2VAoIXuK960520NAL8iQUIbsTT4LRoEl5drxTXDfBEAPxCX+cA9hRKo2VTollak8x9VKTuzmR8c4zEKZhFlYAA==
10 => TxFIQe3ynULLQFyePIJq7v3dybsMMp9krpISG5UsR3qhXkcC50RwAH90n2LA7isxS9Cn2wiHbgKi3v4mLaWnWA==
11 => yhsHdTR7tlxZpoG2LsJWcG9UrNNsCgFf8cfLd/duwRNeD08aKuChv9hSpQAaXAKkkGlqqApmUGDu0G+gRVbLhg==
12 => SqJfMgE5WJoc5ImGoDaXhiYCoXmxVnBA3rDcGHC975Q8mtJMxpU4nxSe67dq+pSH5bpR02Se5QXypHeI/PwGLg==
13 => kbU6SUbAQhcysnw6O3RsjeX1xwKwd9j7L1ejJhhu1APa4ZzjFQmyFX3pHG7tnBitPPXRKxbgu49dRUZOtrtHgA==
14 => K4r4AxmWTZIT7YA+BaGrVWCrdjFk2EiIK+s352FZeAmzDUpiJe8wC6DuVYwfmY8z3krmYlw9k+cHvfAlDFVwZg==
15 => h7qPJz5mhzWPfeiQ+/quMWPmmb8yVjBc8KNvRN95h7Ycw7/nAj9+E19M2q1OaaJnT8xJ/ZzYUM4BV/vSol0Wpg==
16 => WHTn5zz5JY/x0iQf3J0rceaaa5d0J3kPhChrQZsI7t/OU1RSSuumsiEzrPs4m/p/RsCTbI1XBsydoHzOr7Xf8A==
17 => 5BTyu5Iujc6g2j7OhGAQJWqMyqC75lbEXCxUnixB1tse7YuhcrSD4Q977ijC8WGjt+dTxI4XiNWx8pR7p4ixoA==
18 => 0j+GqFg75KPJgeg0f4Tvhr95qNWgyQT8eiK+kRGatXvnO0Guq0LdJlw6LwA2Ymfhr+GBy1HVmahCuzWTjxKTNg==
19 => OGFBWgdqCjkkLSSbxywIekHqVXaXBHbm3NrxVYb+xPELr1efA/0L6S0xjynHH+NxIQ1cyQYlGeMAh+Ks3Rd08Q==


PHP: Salted is: >>>>>>PASSWORD{SALT}<<<<<<
1 => 2yqDGoZ6NrdAKeS/yf7fCT/Zbv0/1Wa7cGwiy1pOvTpFE/I2Xfpajh8ukRhkM6j/8rv90C02ISeaz8K9awJLzw==
2 => QVn8YydCA/9J5j8YTnUlnDXtqq0yNRPVz2m1QFkZ7fwQBWY4rgjP/JUCIjQbL4JRyIZATf3Bsnh0OfhaT52f/A==
3 => ixpdJ4TaAY5POys95nhtU0Ghbu+yDgch3PL0UsPktxVUa5igEEdRmzMH5JZH7SrTkBaHUCa9ThKiSfA/TdbPog==
4 => Am1dkcqXZkXOfDuwsj/VaZy3j3CQnzDzbj1B4g4/dkCJ5g/0nXAti7PKdo5oxm8GIv3AoHHW6eldTbwGj3IgzA==
5 => mrfwPBiT3+TDl41xcf34p0A+eNHP18qWzm0uwOpzAarkfemzV5xsnz/x2QxuE4V7vNgYB8pVV6mYqRQkqitQRA==
6 => JIGX+XD6XVaPwP3LuJO/OToef2jBiCq70mKyg6PmvUARigS5VkZMrcbnI/PXdHXrZ081fVMYavJRsXJiXRhiaQ==
7 => oqU+PpM+HqJmUKcmOUMtIxvPgsCNyJ4zo+986ksr+Wvjp6ejDezFS49NuUXxi03GIj0ueLJxdPlIABvEBpd6RQ==
8 => nf9QhPhXnG7Fnh0t7YRXnfq/JlBUUogt9A8U+7aTA2A834c8SKiGqMgXqm7K7LUPHw3F8jwYxeMyXktPvUmMQQ==
9 => QvttW+hXvBL2DLA5qCfq2205C/6A+YhYRA4YY63Fb7kqGYq3vrQIiSr/xsl/o8HCZr1KZ+lvNw4+ds/r/yqmBg==
10 => tP0kRYQ1k3VAWXGqkHVh+i00e8WMODwmSh9UHtIcJm97sKVpum6iUzfKSEEHWbfjyUGG2P/+jgZLOe4LV1Rmig==
11 => Wxmdu8t1VCMf/6Inax8jCzCSOUEwiDDugoQafE4lYN8k5NkCXUyIvXINcg0Di5ayW0NnxNuOEmmXR6rdTopyrA==
12 => cNUPNmfJyCBZ6zKVaB2UCiiKyKzNKREPv7cBFCJFdrCB4t1Vqaw3TmldrjOiclJ3+w3tx4rTn2P1K1nP2SMcKg==
13 => AT1LD3sETQe50HmVcHmqgY6emY+sT0OZPSIRffKjHfV1xktejbQnGE1evfrls5MpacULmzgNJccjsbWnDomsVA==
14 => Um02XaFEiRm7oxQAQ7pUsxXxnhI9M6xSymapkKPrHBmhjrgcSPimMQ9tUi9Vc7H5OJlAvW0svM2e45pwZfxh+w==
15 => 68vct/q024/3EppVZo4fw4vWI2IYN/99RsjI7ebvrv6GZL0xwqV3ERXynGuLdTlILwQyovM9QA7tvRNduu3qqQ==
16 => PRfC+T2nLT9NRk/k+/XZ/UoNHYWGJR7naRLSX16+++rzjFVDMOnrQYFqEHWf+qTxqPMrS2NmyoD4P9pNr5d16A==
17 => N3l3MBljhgzNsd7K3x6dU9btwAlTaJMk/8S7Jp9ICrOss6FVc+hMKYkUuiuE1vT+P3DK6s+NeArWS8/DtBGyug==
18 => ihidFTx2BPBhHvq0WZ9yVEPoYciKApNsm9mSvSArZsf75rWrJRFA1fluusKllwNXPvbZinLczd8d8EQLNnsG5A==
19 => EDo6YqOQaUmd0Vp8cGZPe5G4Dta2j/JFtc4W4aYQLo5+OvKdolzLu6YLK3GjKHCJdpbj1fUsH7sKxH98UyFhxA==
```

Outputting the raw digests will show that by iteration 8 the digest starts and ends equal to the one in PHP, but there are a few bytes different in the middle.
Any ideas why this is happening?
As anyone experienced similar results?
I need to do this so that I can hash passwords on a legacy system.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `memcpy(digest, h_result.raw_hash, sizeof(h_result.raw_hash));` <- shouldn't that be `h_result.hash_len`? Otherwise you could be reading uninitialized memory.

Comment: Here’s a hint: the digest of iteration 7 (the last one before they diverge) contains a zero byte.

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up!

Answer (score 1):

Don't use any string based functions on binary data, such as:

```
strlen(message)
```

or your code will fail.

Comment: A word of advice: when someone asks you a question about C, in a venue such as this, the right answer is never "use another language". If you read my OP closely, you will notice that I'm doing this in order to migrate data from a legacy system (on that same system).
Actually, I only made this (dumb) mistake exactly because I've moved on to other languages long ago. Come to think of it, last time I programmed in C was precisely 28 years ago.